# I'm having trouble with webcrawler coding in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to use PyCharm to code a web crawler but I keep running into errors that seem strange to me.

For example:

- I will type `import urlparse` into the PyCharm console but `import` won't highlight orange.
- I also get an `end of statement expected` notification after typing: `print urls[0]`.

Can anyone answer why I'm running into strange errors while the tutorial video shows the guy typing the same code without any problems? Could it be that I'm using Python 3 and he's using Python 2?

> I removed the web addresses because of the link limit in stackoverflow

Here is the code from the mentioned issues:

```
import urlparse
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ""

urls = [url] # stack of urls to scrape
visited = [url] # historic record of urls

while len(urls) >0:
    try:
        htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
    except:
        print urls[0]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

    urls.pop(0)

    print soup.findAll('a', href=True):
```

Here is the code I copied from another tutorial that doesn't show the results the same as in the video (the code runs but doesn't give any lists in console):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = '' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'a': 'character.php?ID=44029'}):
            href = "" + link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print(href)
        page += 1

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "character.php?ID=44029")
    for item_name in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'character.php?ID=44029'}):
        print(item_name.string)

trade_spider(10)
```

**Console output:**

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Atom/PycharmProjects/youtubeTNB/main_vid25_HowToBuildWebCrawler.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

Comment: As you can see in your second code snippet you need to use `print` as a function in python 3, e.g. `print(urls[0])`. This could be one of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

> I will type import urlparse into the PyCharm console but import won't
>   highlight orange.

`urlparse` does not seem to be used in the code you posted, PyCharm detects that it is not used. Or it could be that you don't have the `urlparse` module installed. If you mouse-over that line in your code, PyCharm will tell you what it has detected.

> I also get an end of statement expected notification after typing:
>   print urls[0].

This is because you are using Python 3 and the tutorial use Python 2. Like @TobiMarg commented, you need to use `print` as a function in python 3. And you have a colon at the end of the print statement that should not be there.